# Getting an "Unable to convert connection to SSL (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)"

Tags: java

I have configured an email notification using Javax.mail with the following properties:

```
mail.smtp.host=mail.mycompany.com
mail.from=Notification Email <mycompany.notifications@mycompany.com>
mail.smtp.auth=false
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
mail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2
mail.smtp.port=587
mail.smtp.ssl.trust=mail.mycompany.com
mail.smtp.debug=true
```

But I'm receiving the following error:

```
  javax.mail.MessagingException: Unable to convert connection to SSL (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)
            at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.util.MailConnection.getConnectedTLSSocket(MailConnection.java:543)
            at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPConnection.getConnectedTLSSocket(SMTPConnection.java:849)
            at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPConnection.sendHandshake(SMTPConnection.java:815)
            at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPConnection.protocolConnect(SMTPConnection.java:149)
            at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:165)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:340)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:186)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1279)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:401)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:373)
        at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.util.MailConnection.getConnectedTLSSocket(MailConnection.java:532)
```